# Python: Having trouble calling classes from dicts

Tags: python, class, dictionary, init

I'm new to object-oriented programming, and was playing around with Python using classes in dictionaries when I ran into a wall.

I created parent and child classes, and inserted the child classes into a dict in another class `dictionary`:

```
class zero(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('This is some text')


class one(zero):
    def execute(self):
        print(0+1)


class two(zero):
    def execute(self):
        print(0+2)


class three(zero):
    def execute(self):
        print(0+3)


class dictionary(object):   
    numbers = {
        1: one(),
        2: two(),
        3: three()
    }

dictionary.numbers[3].execute()
```

When I did this, the program immediately printed the __init__ of the child classes before proceeding to execute the command on the last line.

I'm not sure why this is happening, because I only expected the last line to produce output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing's wrong. Here:

```
{
        1: one(),
        2: two(),
        3: three()
}
```

The `()` literally calls, for example, `one.__init__()` (after creating the object with `one.__new__()`). This is done for all three objects.

Anyway, whenever you're instantiating a class' instance with `SomeClass(some, arguments)`, you're calling the class' `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method of a class is called the 'constructor' and is executed when an object is created from the class (you will often, for example, see variables passed to the class when the object is being created, and the `__init__` method will be used to accept the variables and populate internal class variables with their values).

classes `one`, `two`, and `three` all subclass (or inherit) from class `zero` -- you can see that all three of the class definitions include a reference to `zero` in the line that defines the class name, e.g., `def one(zero):` -- so they all automatically inherit the `__init__` method from the `zero` class.

So, when you assign `one()`, `two()`, and `three()` to the numbers `dict` in the `dictionary` class, they are all essentially executing the constructor `__init__` method from `zero`, which contains the statement to print the text, before you then explicitly call the `execute` method of the third element in the numbers `dict` in `dictionary`.